# My question about Nexus Mod Manager was locked, other questions about the program are allowed

Tags: support

I have a question about my Arqade post: [How does Nexus Mod Manager install mods?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310496/how-does-nexus-mod-manager-install-mods)

I asked a general question about functionality of the program. [There are nearly ten questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Anexus%20mod%20manager) about NMM on the site, none are locked.
Why the question is off-topic? I can limit the scope to Bethesda games, if required.

Comment: A locked question is different than a closed one.  Only moderators can lock questions.  [See this question as an example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258225/why-does-the-original-game-boy-support-four-shades-of-grey), which was also closed.  Locked questions cannot be commented on, voted on, and new answers cannot be posted.  Existing answers cannot be commented or voted on either.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is placed on-hold, not locked. It's an important distinction, because it means that you **can** still edit your question to clarify what you mean and focus your question down to the core issue that you want to solve, and it may get reopened.

We don't really do "under the hood" looks at gamer-specific software like Launchers or Mod managers, so questions on "*how*" something works aren't really allowed here. Which is probably why your question was initially closed based on the title of your question.

*However*, I can see in your question body that you've asked a few separate distinct questions:

1. Does Nexus Mod Manager overwrite game files?
2. Where does NMM put mod files?
3. How are mods that contain scripts handled?
4. Do I have to launch the game via NMM?

I *wouldn't* consider questions 1, 2 or 4 'under the hood' questions, at least from my experience with modding Fallout 3 using FOMM (an older version of NMM). Most people who have fiddled with the Bethesda-game mod managers before should be able to answer these.

Question 3 on the other hand: not many gamers are going to know how scripts are handled and this isn't knowledge they would pick up from using the application itself.

I also think that the answers may vary from game to game, so specifically stating which game (or games) that you're asking about would help.

---

So here's what I propose you should do:

- Explicitly state the game(s) you're asking about.
- Edit your question to focus on Questions 1 and 2 above.
- Remove question 3 entirely.
- Have question 4 as an addendum (it's a simple yes/no and I don't think it needs to stand on its own).

For example:

> ### Does Nexus Mod Manager overwrite base game files?
>
> > The Nexus Mod Manager is a free and open source piece of software that allows you to download, install, update and manage your files through an easy to use interface. It integrates with the Nexus sites [nexusmods.com]
>
> I'm looking at modding [Skyrim], and I'm wondering where NMM places the mod files? Does it overwrite the original game files when replacing stuff like textures?
>
> Also, do I have to launch [Skyrim] via NMM or can I launch it normally?

I believe something like this would be answerable by us.

Comment: I agree with this, those proposed questions at the end are things I could provide an answer to. +1, thanks for the detailed input on this!

Comment: I think question 3 is still valid. If replacing textures is acceptable, so is replacing scripts IMO. Removing or keeping question 3 would not make this question any more or less valid to me.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud - Fair enough. My problem with it is on the basis of asking *'how'* it works with scripts specifically. Other than "NMM places the mod containing scripts in <directory> just like any other mod" there isn't much we can say without diving into the internals of NMM. *Where* it places/overwrites scripts, textures etc, sure no problem, that's something we with our 'gamer' hat on will be able to answer.

Comment: @Robotnik Also fair points.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed as it wasn't asking a gaming related question ("how do I install mods with NMM?" etc) but a development related, meta, under-the-hoods question ("how does it work?" etc), as visible in the close reason.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my question. I have no intention to develop mods, hence the question isn't "development-related". Title could be clearer, though.

Comment: I Know, but the question is not gaming related. Asking how it works is a development related question.

Comment: @CC. Development is a bit of a loose term. Even though you're not asking how to develop mods, you're asking how the mods are installed, which is in itself a development question.

Comment: @CC. Nexus Mods has a forum that is much more likely to get you the kind of answer you're looking for.  https://forums.nexusmods.com

Comment: @MadMAxJr: I prefer not to go there as I have encountered people wiping their entire history with scripts on other forums. I have received an answer to my question, only for it to be deleted (or edited) afterwards.